# Ubuntu 20.04 snaps: Allow a snap app access to a VM shared folder

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, snap, apparmor

I have Ubuntu 20.04 guest system with a shared folder (lets say, `/home/me/VMShared`) between guest and host. On the guest machine user `me` is added to `vboxsf` group which allows full access to this folder. However, when I run a Snap Application (namely, Figma), it doesn't have access to that folder. In `dmesg` I see that access is blocked by AppArmor:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1709652605.397:589): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.figma-linux.figma-linux" name="/home/user/VMShared/" pid=8342 comm="pool" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor#checking-and-debugging-denies-6

Comment: @Samveen thank you for the link. Am I supposed to directly edit corresponding app armor profile for the snap application, or is there a way to do this using snap itself?

Comment: what bothers me is that this profile was created by snap, so if I edit it, there might be some errors in the future, or it will be overwritten during update etc

Comment: Distribution provided app armor profiles follow the logic of the least common denominator, and very rarely will they change in such a way to cause you issues. That said, you should be able to fix any issues that crop up the same way you fix them now.